# SASS - compile scss file to css file does not work [v1.32.0 compiled with dart2js 2.10.4]

Tags: sass

I am trying to compile a simple example:

```
$font-stack: Helvetica, sans-serif; 
$primary-color: #333; 
body { font: 100% $font-stack; color: $primary-color; }
```

However sass raise the error:

```
Error reading ..\..\..\..\System Volume Information: operation not permitted.
```

The command used was:

```
sass input.scss output.css
```

My command line was opened as administrator and both files exist.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem by upgrading node.js from v12.13.0 to v14.15.3

I hope this is useful for someone